# How to design a digestive system for filtering insects out of sand?

Tags: biology, creature-design, science-fiction, xenobiology

The idea for this animal is it filters through the sand to catch small insect-like creatures that are 2-6 inches long. I'm thinking of giving it a sieve-like pouch of skin at its throat that filters out most of the small grains of sand. I'm also thinking that maybe it could have a separate track for the larger grains of sand to go through a different path in the digestive system.
Another possible way to do this is to make it only swallow the insect-like creatures and spit out the sand. Maybe a combination of all of them.

Comment: Better use the term "sieve" instead of "filter" for this. A filter does fluids

Comment: Have you looked at the feeding pattern of walrus? They target bivalves that are often buried.

Comment: Why did you edit in "(CLOSED)"? The question might be concluded for you, but as part of this platform that really doesn't matter.

Comment: Meet the [Parrotfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrotfish).  *Whether they feed on coral, rock or seagrasses, the substrate is ground up between the pharyngeal teeth. After they digest the edible portions from the rock, they excrete it as sand, helping create small islands and the sandy beaches.*

Comment: +1 nice edit, @J... THAT would be a nice answer ! Confirm, I found *"An island in the Maldives is made of parrotfish poop. Parrotfish munch on rocky coral and excrete sand. That sand, a new study finds, is important for building reef islands"* https://www.sciencenews.org/blog/wild-things/island-maldives-made-parrotfish-poop (countdown banner alas)

Comment: Ah ok.. well thanks @J.. , I'll see if I can find some relevant info about these fish.. but of course meanwhile someone else could run away with it (grin smiley)

Comment: Why does the throat-sieve filter out only "most" of the sand? How large is a grain, compared to creatures 2-6 inches long? (In insect terms aren't creatures 2-6 inches long not "small" but rather "huge"?)

Why would a separate track for larger grains be a problem? 

How would making it only swallow the insect-like creatures and spit out the sand be another way to do this, rather than exactly what you'd already described?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Baleen whale style?**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_feeder#Baleen_whales

> The baleen whales (Mysticeti), one of two suborders of the Cetacea
> (whales, dolphins, and porpoises), are characterized by having baleen
> plates for filtering food from water, rather than teeth... Baleen
> whales typically seek out a concentration of zooplankton, swim through
> it, either open-mouthed or gulping, and filter the prey from the water
> using their baleens. A baleen is a row of a large number of keratin
> plates attached to the upper jaw with a composition similar to those
> in human hair or fingernails.

I am thinking here of a sand eater that eats sand and bugs then spits out the sand and keeps the bugs.  The flap would be like baleen to keep bugs in and let sand out.  Gray whales do essentially this with their baleen - they eat giant mouthfuls of mud from the bottom of the sea and then let the mud particles and water out, keeping clams and worms.

Comment: Nice  perhaps worth being a bit more explicit for some that the 'bugs' it's sifting from the sand must all be bigger than particles of sand? unless they do it like Logan's answer and just swallow the sand without any filtering.

Comment: I am thinking that instead of squeezing the dry sand out, if this creature is an air breather it could blow the sand out thru the baleen.  Which would be a spectacular spurt of sand and also whale-like.  Vibrations help moving sand grains not lock up against each other and it is easy to impart vibratons to air movement: vocalization.  The sand spurt would be accompanied by a characteristic groaning rumble.

Comment: That could work for a self-defense action and intimidation of other males when fighting over a mate, maybe in social situations too

Answer (score 15):

There are real creatures which eat silt and sand to extract nutrients from tiny critters or dead organic matter mixed into it.

None of them (Edit: with the exception of baleen whales, which just recruit their existing water expulsion system to carry along sand and silt as well) bother with mechanically filtering out the sand. They just allow the inert, non-digestible sand to pass through the digestive system, like geological dietary fiber, and poop it out.

Depending on the precise nature of the sand, this may have very little or quite a lot of effect on the digestive system. For example, creatures which eat a lot of carbonate sand tend to lose their stomachs--the oesophagus just leads directly to an intestine, 'cause the minerals they inject would just neutralize any stomach acid anyway.

Answer (score 4):

First things first: what do you mean by a flap? if you mean an opening, is it pulled taut? Though to me that would make sense, it wouldn't fit the definition of a flap. Is it fixed or is it movable via muscle, tendon, or other means? Is it opposable? Can the animal control the flap? Is it pure instinct or somewhere in between like breathing?

Another thing: the idea of a filter is, to put it lightly, an absurd notion. Water filters need to be replaced regularly to function correctly so an organic one would likely be useless within less than a year, not to mention the likely emergence of infections in the organism.

Though I will give you the benefit of the doubt and, rather than a pored mesh, it is a more colander-like organ that acts like a sift. If we ignore the fact that it would be inevitable that some stone would pass through the throat, as I'm assuming it's swallowing mouthfuls, and depending on the size of the animal to survive on a purely insectoid diet it would need to eat almost constantly.

Finally, according to the idea of the evolutionary arms race, the insectoid animals would gradually get closer to the size of the stone in their area and would become undetectable to the animal's organ.

This is not the final word, nor does it dismiss the interesting aspects but these are the things that came to my mind (in the realm of issues).

Comment: Agree +1, but you don't need to qualify things, it is a clear explanation as is. I've put it in a comment, maybe "sieve" is meant, not "filter" ;)